# How to build an eventual return value though multiple promises

Tags: node.js, promise

How do I chain some promises (NodeJS) together to continually enhance and object with new data and return the final object at the end of the chain.  ie:

```
return getOrder().then((order) => {
    
    return StatusMachine.getStatus(order.orderId);
    
}.then((status) => { 
    
    // get status response
    // how do I access the "Order" in the previous then
    // so I can do something like 
    order.status = status;
    return order;
    
}).then((order) => {

    return Shipping.getTrackingNumber(order.orderId);

}).then((tracking) => {

    order.trackingNumber = tracking;
    return order

});
```

Goal here is to load an order, then query its status and add it to the order, then query its tracking number and add it to the order.  Currently, I'm setting Order as a global variable so that I can access it from every then() function and then in the final then(), I'm simply returning the global Order variable.  However, that doesn't feel right.

Comment: Use async/await syntax, then it's trivial. Or pass an object through, accumulating props as it goes.

Comment: passing the order though meaning create a new object to hold the order object and the status promise?  like return {order: OrderObject, status: statusPromise} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `order` & `status` you need to wrap it with `async` function like this.

```
getOrder()
  .then(async (order) => { // <--
    const status = await StatusMachine.getStatus(order.orderId)  // <-- await for status
    return { order, status }
  })
  .then(({ status, order }) => {
    order.status = status
    return Promise.resolve(order) // if you are going to chain `.then` again then you have to return promise (converting this to async function will also works) 
  })
//.....
```

But I high recommend going full `async`, its much more readable and error handling becomes super easy

```
const getOrderWithMetadata = async () => {
  const order = await getOrder()
  const status = await StatusMachine.getStatus(order.orderId)
  order.status = status
  const tracking = await Shipping.getTrackingNumber(order.orderId)
  order.trackingNumber = tracking
  return order
}
```

or with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
const getOrderWithMetadataBetter = async () => {
  const order = await getOrder()
  const [status, tracking] = await Promsie.all([ // waits for both to complete, throws error if anyone of them fails. 
    StatusMachine.getStatus(order.orderId),
    Shipping.getTrackingNumber(order.orderId),
  ])
  order.status = status
  order.trackingNumber = tracking
  return order
}
```

---

Edit: It depends on how you want to handle error.

case 1: Ignore errors

```js
const getOrderWithMetadata = async () => {
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (err) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

case 2: return data and error (like `go` lang does.)

```js
const getOrderWithMetadata = async () => {
  try {
    // ...
    return [value, null] // [result, error]
  } catch (err) {
    // ...
    return [null, err] // [result, error]
  }
}

const [data, err] = await getOrderWithMetadata()
```

case 3: handle error outside using `try/catch`

```js
const getOrderWithMetadata = async () => {
  //...
}

try {
  // ...
  await getOrderWithMetadata()
  //...
} catch (err) {
  // ...
}
```

case 4: handle error outside using `promise`

```js
const getOrderWithMetadata = async () => {
  //...
}

getOrderWithMetadata().then(() => /* ... */).catch(() => /* ... */)
```

Comment: I went with your method of using awaits.  The only issue here is error handling.  How are you doing error handling in this case? wrap it with a try/catch? or anything more elegant?

Comment: @majestiq I have updated my answer with error handling strategies, so check it out.